# Accessing OWA using HTTWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, outlook-web-app

what's up?

I'm trying to make a request to an OWA website and log in an user account. Has someone already tried it before?
My application will be a console application and the main idea is check if OWA is working fine comparing HTML response.

I got the POST request, but after that I have a redirect (code 302) and I didnt get the response with HTML rigth.

My code:

```
        //GET
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://domain/owa");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;


        // POST
        string getUrl = "https://domain/owa/auth.owa";
        string postData = "destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain%2Fowa%2Fauth.owa&flags=0&forcedownlevel=0&trusted=0&username=myuser&password=mypassword&isUtf8=1";
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); 
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
        newStream.Close();

        response = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
```

After that, my response has a html page saying I need to allow javascript to run it. But I understand that HTTPWerRequest objet is unable to run js.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked into using exchange web services to get the mail?

Comment: Hi Soner, I needed to do in this way (using httpwebrequest object). After a long search, I found out each version of Microsoft Outlook Web Access has different links. In my case I change to https://extranet.netwall.com.br/owa/auth/owaauth.dll.